# Подскажите что за функция

Tags: winapi, reverse-engineering

Начал обучаться реверсу, для патча древней игрушки под новые системы, и столкнулся с проблемой:

Обычно экзешники начинаются с winMain, но этот winMain в коде древней игры отсутствует

```
    int undefined192939239(HMODULE param_1,undefined4 param_2,int *param_3)
    
    {
      int iVar1;
      void *local_14;
      undefined *puStack_10;
      undefined *puStack_c;
      undefined4 local_8;
      
      puStack_c = &DAT_004dc3b8;
      puStack_10 = &LAB_00480784;
      local_14 = ExceptionList;
      local_8 = 0;
      ExceptionList = &local_14;
      iVar1 = FUN_004131e0(param_1,param_3);
      if (DAT_00513e28 != '\0') {
        MessageBoxA((HWND)0x0,"Wrong CD","Error",0);
      }
      ExceptionList = local_14;
      return iVar1;
    }
```

Что это может быть за функция ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/entry-entry-point-symbol?view=msvc-170

Comment: Если коротко - функция вызывает функцию FUN_004131e0 и видимо делает проверку результата вызова (предположительно наличия игрового CD в дисковое). Это в принципе все, что можно сказать по приведенному фрагменту кода.

Comment: Вообще, часть логики мог декомпилятор не расшифровать и просто пропустить. Лучше дизассемблерный листинг смотреть.